# RecyclerView items' selected state not being respected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this weird problem with my project. I recently switched from ListView to RecyclerView and as a result, selected style of items in navigation drawer is not being respected. 
This is how I'm generating my navigation drawer:

```
Navigation drawer item layout:
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

```
RecyclerView layout:

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground" />
```

Navigation layout inside which the drawer fragment resides:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="MaterialNavbar.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'm creating navigation drawer via [Android Material Drawer](https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template). The result is as follows:

[image]

And this is how it used to look with `ListView` in a fragment instead of `RecyclerView`:

[image]

I don't really know what the problem is and how can I solve it. It is very annoying really. Thank you for your help.

**Update:** Link to RecyclerView adapter class as asked. http://pastebin.com/V5R6sve5

Comment: Please post your RecyclerAdapter class

Comment: @Smashing I just updated the question and added the link.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is or the desired behaviour is.

Comment: @William The selected color is not respected by the navigation drawer items. As you can see in the first gif, while I keep my finger on a list item, a selected change occurs and it goes back to its initial color value. The second gif portrays how it should be. i.e. as long as my finger's down and on a particular item, it should remain selected.

Comment: @BasitSaeed sounds like an issue with your drawable then

Comment: @William I don't have a drawable set to navigation drawer items. It is happening in a navigation drawer's adapter (in `onBindViewHolder`):


`if (mSelectedPosition == i || mTouchedPosition == i) {  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
} else { viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); }`